# ML model to transform words

Tags: neural-network, nlp, conv-neural-network

I build model that on input have correct word. On output there is possible word written by human (it contain some errors). My training dataset looks that:

```
input - output  
hello - helo  
hello - heelo  
hello - hellou  
between - betwen  
between - beetween  
between - beetwen  
between - bettwen  
between - bitween
```

etc.
During preprocessing I add a measure of the distortion of a word. Then I hardcoding letters for numbers.
My current model's using CNN. The number of neurons of input is the same as the longest word in training dataset and the number of neurons of output is the same as the longest word in traning dataset. 
This model doesn't work as I excepted. Word on the output is not look as I except.
eg.

```
input - output
house - gjrtdd
```

Question:

How can I build/improve model for this task? Is CNN a good idea? What other methods can I use for this task?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How can I build/improve model for this task? Is CNN a good idea? What other methods can I use for this task?

Comment: None of these questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow. Maybe it would be better if you ask in https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or http://datascience.stackexchange.com/